# Can't play Steel Storm, Burning Retribution

Tags: software-center, games

I've bougth Steel Storm, Burning Retribution in the Software Center, and every time I run it shows the following message:

**You have reached this menu due to missing or unlocable content/data**

**You may consider adding**

***-base dir /path/to/game***

**to your launch commandline**

I've gone to **main menu** in the preferences tab and changed the launcher to no avail.

I've tried running it from console, with  `/opt/steelstorm-episode2/steelstorm`, I got:

```
Game is Steel-Storm using base gamedir gamedata
Steel-Storm Linux 01:07:07 Jun 11 2011 - release
Playing shareware version.
Skeletal animation uses SSE code path
DPSOFTRAST available (SSE2 instructions detected)
Failed to init SDL joystick subsystem:
couldn't exec quake.rc
couldn't exec default.cfg
execing config.cfg
couldn't exec autoexec.cfg
Client using an automatically assigned port
Client opened a socket on address 0.0.0.0:0
Client opened a socket on address [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:0
Linked against SDL version 1.2.12
Using SDL library version 1.2.14
GL_VENDOR: NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER: GeForce 6150SE nForce 430/PCI/SSE2/3DNOW!
GL_VERSION: 2.1.2 NVIDIA 270.41.06
vid.support.arb_multisample 1
vid.mode.samples 0
vid.support.gl20shaders 1
Video Mode: fullscreen 640x480x32x0.00hz
S_Startup: initializing sound output format: 48000Hz, 16 bit, 2 channels...
Wanted audio Specification:
    Channels  : 2
    Format    : 0x8010
    Frequency : 48000
    Samples   : 2048
Obtained audio specification:
    Channels  : 2
    Format    : 0x8010
    Frequency : 48000
    Samples   : 1024
Sound format: 48000Hz, 2 channels, 16 bits per sample
CDAudio_Init: No CD in player.
Can't get initial CD volume
CD Audio Initialized
```

If I try `-base /opt/steelstorm-episode2/steelstorm` says "command not found".

Comment: You have to add `-base /opt/steelstorm-episode2/steelstorm` to the command, not make that the command itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### diagnosis

The error message in the question gives a clue.

```
Game is Steel-Storm using base gamedir gamedata
couldn't exec quake.rc
couldn't exec default.cfg
execing config.cfg
couldn't exec autoexec.cfg
```

Steelstorm cannot figure out where the correct base-directory containing the files above.

### solution

Fortunately Steelstorm has a parameter which can specify this base-directory

To start the application from the command line you should use the following format:

```
/opt/steelstorm-episode2/steelstorm -basedir /opt/steelstorm-episode2/
```

[source, post #31](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1706549&page=4)

Alternatively, edit the Steel-storm menu option - changing the command line to the above.

For natty you can start the menu application by typing `alacarte` or using the dash and searching for `main menu`.

If you do not have `alacarte` installed - you can install this via:

#### [alacarte](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte) [image: Install alacarte]

Comment: What happens?... well, it works. Thank you!